# Elegant way to do a string prefix test

Tags: c++, string, c++14, std

As far as I know, there is no facility in the standard library to do this directly. So, I'm wondering a simple and elegant way to do this. Note that I don't intent to write a `is_prefix()` function myself. Just use what are already there in the standard library. Suppose the task is to test whether `a` is a prefix of `b` (both are of type `std::string`).

The most succinct way seems to be `b.find(a) == 0`. But it takes `O(a.size() * b.size())` time. No good.

Also, we can do `b.substr(0, a.size()) == a`. This takes linear time. But it creates a new string object, which possibly involves dynamic memory allocation on the heap. So, no good.

We can write `b.size() >= a.size() && std::equal(b.begin(), b.begin() + a.size(), a.begin())`. This is optimal in terms of runtime performance, but the code is lengthy.

Any suggestions?

For those of you wondering why I'm asking this, I want to find a handy solution to use in TopCoder SRMs and job interviews.

Comment: Regarding `std::equal`, you can also use the variant with 4 parameters: `std::equal(b.begin(), b.begin() + a.size(), a.begin(), a.end())`. IMO this isn't that "lengthy" and quite nice in fact.

Comment: @Hiura `b.begin() + a.size()` may be out of range.

Comment: Oh... very good observation!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`std::mismatch`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch) algorithm:

```
bool is_prefix(const std::string& data, const std::string& prefix)
{
    auto mismatch = std::mismatch(data.begin(),   data.end(),
                                  prefix.begin(), prefix.end()).second;
    return mismatch == prefix.end();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I think this is actually quite nice. So, a one liner would be `std::mismatch(b.begin(), b.end(), a.begin(), a.end()).second == a.end()`.

Comment: @Lingxi Yes. I only wrote it in two lines for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

For people stuck with older Visual Studio versions:

Since str must be at least as long as prefix, we can use the 3 parameter-version and no longer need newer c++ standards.

```
std::mismatch(prefix.begin(), prefix.end(), str.begin()).first == prefix.end();
```